# Different driver for the same device in two accounts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, user-accounts, gpu, amd-graphics-card

I have a PC with multiple GPUs that I use for computational processing, for gaming and for mining. Depending on the use, there are different drivers to use (as opposed to profiles in the same driver). However, I don't want to have to uninstall, install, configure multiple times a week. When I change the driver in one profile, it seems that it is a system wide change. Is it possible to have different drivers for a device in different accounts in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. During setup of the drivers, the drivers are copied to `System32\drivers` folder and loaded here. So this is a system wide setting and no user side setting.

Install 2 Windows versions side by side, dual boot them and install the correct driver for the purpose you need in each installation.